# How do I change an image dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a little banner thing and my main image is not displaying

The code seems to be working correctly, yet nothing is showing up.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
var urlString = 'url(images/mainphoto' + ss_i + '.jpg)';
var obj = document.getElementById("mainphoto");
obj.style.background = urlString;
//document.getElementById("mainphoto").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/mainphoto" + ss_i + ".jpg')";
console.log(urlString);
```

```
<div id="mainphoto"></div>
```

```
#mainphoto {
    background:url(images/mainphoto0.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 149px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the console output anything? In Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: yes:url(images/mainphoto3.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto0.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto1.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto2.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto3.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto0.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto1.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto2.jpg) hotelstest.html:52
url(images/mainphoto3.jpg

Comment: is it possible to attach the entire script here?

Comment: It maybe a path problem, url(images/mainphoto0.jpg) is relative to the  css file path, but with obj.style.background, it is relative to the html page path, so check the network in dev tools, see if there're 404  errors.

Comment: Does the element have width and height? It does not expand to fit the background!

Comment: probably the paths are wrong. Look in the NETWORK console to check if there are any 404s. CHange the path, add ./ or the direct path before the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `div` is empty, so it won't show i guess, try add `width` and `height` to the div's style

Comment: well, it's a bit off because of the way I'm resetting the array when it reaches its limits --would you know an fix?  I posted it here:http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/hotelstest.html  Perhaps, you can also aid me in changing the text hotel names and prices dynamically too...THANK YOU!